# How to analyze MAT with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, out-of-memory, mat

My web application is running in apache tomcat.

The classloader/component `org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0x7a199fae8` occupies 1,70,86,32,104 (88.08%) bytes.

The memory is accumulated in one instance of `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment[]` loaded by `<system class loader>`.

I got this problem while analyzing Heapdump. How to analyze it further ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide very little information so I only can provide very little advice… ;-)

First you need to find out who is using the largest objects (the `HashMap` in your case). Try to look at the contents of the `HashMap` so you may find out what it is used for. You should also try to look at where this objects are referenced.

Than you can try to limit its size. Depending on whether it is used by a framework you use or by your own code this can be easy (e.g. configuration change for a frameworks cache), medium (e.g. you need to refactor your own code) or difficult (e.g. it is deeply buried in a library you have no control over).

Often the culprit is not the one you expect: Only because an object instance (in your case the `HashMap`) accumulates a lot of memory does not mean the "owner" of this object is the root cause of the problem. You might well have to look some levels above or below in the object tree or even in a completely different location. In most cases it is crucial that you know your application very well.

**Update:** You can try to inspect the contents of a `HashMap` by right clicking it and selecting *Java Collections*, *Hash Entries*. For general objects you can use *List objects*, *with incoming references* (to list all objects that reference the selected object) or *with outgoing references* (to list all object that are referenced by the selected object).

---

Memory analysis is not an easy task and can require a lot of time, at least if you are not used to it…

If you need further assistance you need to provide more details about your application, the frameworks you use and how the heap looks like in MAT.

Comment: Thank you for the information given. However, i am not able find how to view the contents of HashMap objects. Also, I have found useful by reading the below help document for analyzing heap dump using MAT - http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/01/21/10-tips-for-using-the-eclipse-memory-analyzer/

Comment: @Tamilselvan: I updated my answer with how to inspect a `HashMap`.